# Determine if XML node contains text followed by a specific child element using xpath/xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to identify cases where an element contains a random text string followed by a specific child element that also contains a random string.  For example:

```
<paragraph>Here's some text and here's a <word>child</word></paragraph>
```

This is part of a stylesheet, so xpath should be used.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k it's clear to me ...

Comment: @o11c:  Then you're clairvoyant because the question is dripping in ambiguity.  OP: Start by clarifying what you mean by "random" (twice) and whether "following" is essential and whether it implies immediately.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks! I interpreted "random" as "arbitrary" btw.

Comment: The contents of the string is "random" in that I don't know what it will contain, and it does not matter to me (so long as it is valid text that doesn't trigger escape). "Random" or "arbitrary"?  You can tell me if my terminology is wrong in the case.  "Followed by" meaning the child follows the text string.  You could say "immediately followed by", as in, no elements would occur between the text string and the specific child node, but there could be white space at the end of the string.  I don't know if this would cloud the definition of "immediate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `following-sibling::` axis.

With this XML document:

```
<root>
  <paragraph>Here's some text and here's a <word>child</word>.</paragraph>
  <paragraph>Here's some text with no child.</paragraph>
  <paragraph>Here's some text with another <word>child</word>.</paragraph>
  <paragraph/>
  <paragraph>Here's some text with any empty <word/>.</paragraph>
</root>
```

The following XPath expression selects the first, third, and fifth paragraphs:

```
//paragraph[text()[following-sibling::word]]
```

If you want to constrain the `word` tag to also have a direct text child, use this to only select the first and third:

```
//paragraph[text()[following-sibling::word[text()]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 //*[text()/following-sibling::*/text()]
```